# Change the title of backbutton in NavigationBar

Tags: ios, iphone, cocoa-touch, storyboard

Following the examples of the many duplicates for this questions, I can't seem to get it right.

I have a UINavigationViewController that has a LoginViewController as the rootViewController. Here I got a button with a segue (push) to a LoginInfoViewController.

In LoginInfoViewController.m:

```
- (void)viewDidLoad
{
    [super viewDidLoad];

    //null
    NSLog(@"%@", self.navigationItem.backBarButtonItem);

    UIBarButtonItem *backButton = [[UIBarButtonItem alloc] initWithTitle:@"Test"
                                                                   style:UIBarButtonItemStyleDone
                                                                  target:nil
                                                                  action:nil];
    self.navigationItem.backBarButtonItem = backButton;

    //not null, still the back button says: "Back"
    NSLog(@"%@", self.navigationItem.backBarButtonItem);
}
```

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You will need to set the `backBarButtonItem` of the controller you are going back to, not the controller you pushed. Move your code to the `LoginViewController` viewDidLoad method.

The navigation controller derives the back button for the navigation bar from the `backBarButtonItem` of the preceding controller in the stack. If the item is nil, it will use the value in the title property of same. If the title is too long to fit, the navigation bar may substitute the string "Back" in place of the title.
If your controller has a custom left bar button item, the navigation bar will ignore the `backButtonItem` property and title presenting the custom button instead.

Answer (score 0):

Set the title of the back button on the view BEFORE. So, if you segue from `LoginViewController`, you set the back button title on the item before you segue to `LoginInfoViewController`

Example:

In the `viewDidLoad` method on `LoginViewController`:

```
UIBarButtonItem *newBackButton = [[UIBarButtonItem alloc] initWithTitle: @"Go back" style: UIBarButtonItemStyleBordered target: nil action: nil];
[[self navigationItem] setBackBarButtonItem: newBackButton];
```

This means you're setting the button on the `LoginViewController`, not on the `LoginInfoViewController`.